# How to define global variables for Twig templates with values coming from the DB?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

I would like to define a global variable for twig, which would be accessible from any template.

I can create a global variable in symfony's `config/packages/twig.yaml`, but I need it to be a value obtained from the database.

In the documentation for twig it says to use this code:

```php
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addGlobal('name', 'value');
```

Where should I use this code so this varible is available for every template?

Comment: You place it inside the controller where you fetch the data, but seeing you are working in symfony you would need to access the `twig` service e.g, `$this->get('twig')->addGlobal('name', $data);` - (*I dont know the name of the service as which `twig` is registered so you would need to check your configuration*)

Comment: Can I put this into any controller? Will it be accessible in any template?

Comment: Every controller with access to the service container, but i'm guessing pretty much every controller

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A relatively clean way of doing would be to add an [event subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html) that would inject the variables globally before the controllers are instantiated.

The problem of doing in the controller, as one of the comments suggested, is that your globals wouldn't be *global* at all, but defined only for that controller.

You could do something like this:

```php
// src/Twig/TwigGlobalSubscriber.php

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Twig\Environment;

class TwigGlobalSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Twig\Environment
     */
    private $twig;
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $manager;

    public function __construct( Environment $twig, EntityManager $manager ) {
        $this->twig    = $twig;
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function injectGlobalVariables( GetResponseEvent $event ) {
        $whatYouWantAsGlobal = $this->manager->getRepository( 'SomeClass' )->findBy( [ 'some' => 'criteria' ] );
        $this->twig->addGlobal( 'veryGlobal', $whatYouWantAsGlobal[0]->getName() );
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [ KernelEvents::CONTROLLER =>  'injectGlobalVariables' ];
    }
}
```

The DB interaction I left deliberately fuzzy, since only you know exactly what do you want to retrieve from there. But you are injecting the `EntityManager` on this subscriber, so it's only a matter of retrieving the appropriate repository and perform the appropriate search.

Once this is done, you could simply do from your twig templates something like:

```
<p>I injected a rad global variable: <b>{{ veryGlobal }}</b></p>
```

Comment: Thanks that's works but in function injectGlobal you must import this class "FilterControllerEvent"

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 5.4

`service.yml`:

```
   App\Twig\TwigGlobalSubscriber:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request }
```

SysParams - my service takes data from the database

src\Twig\TwigGlobalSubscriber.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Twig\Environment;

use App\Service\SysParams;

class TwigGlobalSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    private $twig;

    public function __construct( Environment $twig, SysParams $sysParams ) {
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->sysParams = $sysParams;
    }

    public function injectGlobalVariables() {
        $base_params = $this->sysParams->getBaseForTemplate();
        foreach ($base_params as $key => $value) {
            $this->twig->addGlobal($key, $value);
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [ KernelEvents::CONTROLLER =>  'injectGlobalVariables' ];
    }

    public function onKernelRequest()
    {
    }
}
```